# Local VOIP servers/clients with APIs

Tags: software-recommendation, voip

I have a fleet of Ubuntu kiosk computers that are going to be deployed in the wild. Members of the public will be using them.

I want to add a "press for assistance" button to the app so that if people get stuck, they can talk to a real person. The kiosk hardware will have speakers and a mic. I'd like the process to be:

- They press the button
- Something centrally rings
- A support worker "picks up" the call
- They talk and eventually one of them hangs up.

Alternatively, if the support staff actively spots an issue at a kiosk, I'd like them to be able to start a call without any user interaction.

I also need support staff to be able to identify *which* kiosk is calling in.

A few problems spawn from wanting to do things like this. I need software to handle the calls and I need a way for my application to start (and end) the call.

Things like TeamSpeak and Mumble seem a poor fit for this because I don't want all the kiosks talking to each other, just as I don't want the support staff's voice broadcasting out of every kiosk at once! I guess I'm after a local-only Skype but something I can actively control at the client end.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Industry standard for VOIP is the Asterisk server. Inside it you configure which telephony protocols are supported, who is allowed to call and to whom the calls are routed.

As a client you can use some command-line softphone. It will be easy to integrate it into the project with some shell scripting.

Or you can take a VOIP library that supports SIP, H323 or whatever protocol and integrate it directly into the application. If it is a web application - WebRTC protocol is emerging now.

To start, install some SIP phone with GUI from the Ubuntu repository, set up Asterisk and several accounts on different machines. Call the number of one account from the other.